# Selection of First L Items of ArrayList of size N > L and Insertion to Another ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList l1 of size N and another l2 of size L < N. I want to put the L first items of l1 to l2. I thought to use the for loop of type for(Object obj : l1) to scan my list of size N and then use l2.add(obj) to add elements on l2, but I am not sure if when I reach the max size of l2 (i.e. L) stops inserting items or continues.

Could somebody suggest me a way to do that? Thanx

Comment: whats the criteria, first L or last L ?

Comment: What have you tried? This site does not exist to do your homework for you. Please read the [FAQ].

Comment: the criteria is first L items

Comment: @Raedwald      I am sorry, I should have mentioned that. I have an ArrayList l1 of size N and another l2 of size L < N. I thought to use the for loop of type for(Object obj : l1) to scan my list of size N and then use l2.add(obj) to add elements on l2, but I am not sure if when I reach the max size of l2 (i.e. L) stops inserting items or continues .... I hope I was clear in my explanation ...

Comment: Please update the post with the above comment to show ur efforts

Comment: There must be a simpler way to phrase this question.  How can I get the first n items from an array list?

Answer (score 21):

You can use `List.subList(int, int)` method to get the first L items

```
int L = 2;

List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(inputList.subList(0,L));
```

Comment: When I use this method, I get an outOfBounds exception when the newList reaches its size. That is, I have L = 10,000, which means I should have items with ID from 0 up to 9,999 in the newList. And I get an exception for ID 10,000! I am trying to solve it from yesterday but I cannot figure why this is happening...

Answer (score 11):

Something like the following:

```
    list2.addAll(list1.subList(0, l));
```

Comment: Got it, I didn't know about sublist and their use. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.arraycopy()

Here an example :

```
package test_temp;

public class TestArrayCopy
{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] SRC = {"Hello", "all", "you", "happy", "taxpayers"};
    int dimN = SRC.length;
    int dimL = 4;
    String[] dest = new String[dimL];
    System.arraycopy(SRC, 0, dest, 0, Math.min(dimN, dimL));
    for (int i = 0; i < dimL; i++) System.out.println(dest[i]);
  }

}
```

This will give the following output :

```
Hello
all
you
happy
```

Hope this is wat you expected ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the use of a sublist will do what I want. But good to now anyway arrayCopy for future use!

Comment: Yes, sorry I read Array instead of ArrayList. Normally there's all you need in the java collections !